# Dynamic programming and Bellman optimality principle

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, dynamic-programming, viscosity-solutions

Consider $$V(x)=\inf_{u \in \mathcal{U}}\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda t} f^0(y_x(t), u(t)) d t$$
which is the value function of an optimal control problem with $y_x(t)$ solution of the state equation
\begin{equation}\label{state_eq_finite_dim}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y^{\prime}(t)=f(y(t), u(t)), t>0 \\
y(0)=x \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Then can I say that at an intuitive level $V$ should satisfy the following HJB
\begin{equation*}
\lambda v(x)-H(x, \nabla v(x))=0 \quad \text { in } \mathbb{R}^{n}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation}
H(x, p)=\inf _{u \in U}\{f(x, u) \cdot p+f^0(x,u )\}
\end{equation}
By Bellman's optimality principle, we know that for every $t>0$ it holds that:
\begin{equation}
V(x)=\inf _{u \in \mathcal{U}}\left\{\int_{0}^{t} f^0\left(y_{x}(s), u(s)\right) e^{-\lambda s} d s+V\left(y_{x}(t)\right) e^{-\lambda t}\right\}
\end{equation}
since the lhs of Bellman's optimality principle is independent of $t$ while the rhs depends on $t$ and then we can differentiate formally the rhs and equating it to zero ?(in this way you get the HJB)

Comment: Can you revise your notation again? there are many things that need some more context. Is $f_0$ the same as $f^0$? what is $\upsilon$? what is $D$? In the first equation, why is there a term with $e^{-\lambda t}$ but $V(x)$ does not depend on $t$ explicitly? In that case, is $t$ like a terminal time, and $V(y_x(t))e^{-\lambda t}$ a terminal cost? And as I said before, you define $V(x)$ in terms of $V(y_x)$ and then redefine $V(x)$ in a later step. How is $y^u_x$ different from $y_x$? 

Can you make these statements more clear? Maybe you can show us the reference you are using.

Comment: I fixed and now it should be more clear: $V$ is the value function which happens to be a solution of the HJB pde for $v$

Comment: as reference I am using [Bardi, Martino, and Italo Capuzzo-Dolcetta. Optimal control and viscosity solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equations. Springer Science Business Media, 1997.]

Comment: Ok, just want to point out (for anyone else) that according to the notation in the book you mentioned $D$ is the gradient. Note that this is not a standard notation. Just as a friendly suggestion, try to use the notation the most standard you can. Some of us may be familiar with Dynamic programming, but not under the particular context of the book you are using. Also, what is it that you are asking at the end? If you can plug in $V$ into the HJB by differentiating? Sorry, I'm still trying to understand

Comment: Ok thanks, I corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long to be a comment:

According to the book you mentioned in page 12, the last expression you wrote $h(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f^0\left(y_{x}(s), u(s)\right) e^{-\lambda s} d s+V\left(y_{x}(t)\right) e^{-\lambda t}$ in general will depend on $t$. However, this quantity should be constant regardless of $t$ for the optimal trajectory due to the dynamic programming principle. This is the equivalent to say that if the fastest route from L.A. to Boston passes through Chicago, then it is also the sequence of the fastest route from LA to Chicago and the fastest from Chicago to Boston. And the same goes for any other midpoint in the optimal route from L.A. to Boston. In your case, this roughly means that the for optimal trajectories the functional remains constant regardless of the midpoint $t$: the first term in $h(t)$ i.e. $\int_{0}^{t} f^0\left(y_{x}(s), u(s)\right) e^{-\lambda s} d s$ which is the cost up to $t$ and the second term i.e. $V\left(y_{x}(t)\right) e^{-\lambda t}$ which is the cost to go, are both optimal for any $t$. Thus, $h'(t)=0$ (since its constant) for the optimal route. Then, the nexts steps from the reference you gave lead to the HJB. Is this the part you wanted to be clarified? Please let me now.

Comment: This helps but I wanted to understand, using your notation, how $h'(t)=0$ leads to the HJB. In particular the $\inf_u$ is disappeared in $h'(t)=0$. How do you recover it? I understand the proof when $V$ is regular but I dont see how $h'(t)=0$ leads to the HJB.

Comment: Well it disapeared at the moment you say $h(t)$ is constant. A usual trick is to, instead of computing the $\inf_u$ explicitly, assume you are at the optimal trajectory (the one you would obtain if you computed the $\inf_u$) and look around to see what you find. In this case, you find that if you computed the optimal, the optimal would have to comply that $h(t)$ is constant. So you stick with that instead of the explicit computation of the $\inf_u$.

Comment: In some sense you interchanged the explicit computation of the optimal, with the use of the DP principle. However this leads to the HBJ which you still need to solve. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: yes but in the HJB has the "inf" in it. when you differentiate $h(t)$ here the inf is not present (because we are in an optimal trajectory) and then I obtain an HJB without the "inf"

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I'm trying to follow the book to see how they proceed for this particular functional. My guess up to now is the following: 1) in page 11 they use the $h'(t)=0$ argument to arrive at $\lambda v(y^*(t))-f(y^*(t),u^*(t))\cdot \nabla v(y^*(t))-f^0(y^*(t),u^*(t))=0$. 2) then, they use the fact that $v$ must satisfy the HJB equation, it's not that the HJB equation was derived from the $h'(t)=0$ argument. 3) then, after equation (5.2) they combine both arguments to arrive at the form of the Hamiltonian which does not have the $\inf_u$

Comment: I mean, they already derived the HJB and showed that it applies to the viscous case in pages 2-6. I insist in what I mentioned before, the Hamiltonian evaluated a the optimal case, does not need to have the $\inf_u$. The equation after (5.2) I refer is reads:
$$
H(y^*(t),u^*(t))=-f(y^*(t),u^*(t))\cdot \nabla v(y^*(t))-f^0(y^*(t),u^*(t))
$$
without the $\inf_u$ (using the notation in your post). But the purpose of these arguments are not to obtain the HJB but to characterize the optimal controls $u^*$. The HJB was fomally derived in previous developments using other arguments.

Comment: Yes it is as you said, the Hamiltonian in an optimal case has not the inf anymore. Anyway to obtain the HJB you need to follow the standar proof